# Is it possible to express $\mathcal{L} f(t+a)$ using $F$ (Laplace transforms)

Tags: laplace-transform

Typical notation for Laplace transforms is that $\mathcal{L} f(t) = F(s)$

Is it possible to rewrite $\mathcal{L} f(t+a)$, where $a$ is some arbitrary constant, to have an expression involving $F$? Clearly it would not just be $F(s+a)$... I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal L(f(t)) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} \ dt = F(s)$. So

\begin{align*} 
\mathcal L(f(t+a)) &= \int_0^\infty f(t+a) e^{-st} \ dt \\
& = \int_a^\infty f(p) e^{-s(p-a)} \ dp \\
& = e^{as} \left[ F(s) - \int_0^a f(p) e^{-sp} \ dp \right]
\end{align*}

**EDIT:** Sorry, the last integration switch was a typo. The limits of integration were changed via the substitution $p = t + a$ in the second step. In the final step, we used the fact that
$$\int_0^\infty = \int_0^a + \int_a^\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you! If you have a chance, could you add more details/in between steps here? I'm not familiar with the technique you used to switch from t to p (in particular, why the lower bound becomes a), and I'm not sure how you arrived at the last step either

Comment: Added some more details, hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes that does, thank you very much for the help!